# Is it possible to add a repository group to a repository group in Sonatype Nexus?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I tried to create a hierarchy of repository groups in my [Sonatype Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) installation. One group as the parent, the two others as childs.

But when I browse the storage index of the parent group, I get *Not found* messages behind some of the folders from one child repository. When I browse the storage index of the child, I can see all artifacts just fine.

**Is it possible to have repository groups in groups?**

*Edit* I added a stupid routing that excluded my artifacts from the parent repository... After removing/fixing the routing, the artifacts show up just fine in all repositories and repository groups.

Comment: have you set the "browsing" enabled on these repos?  The config allows you to have a group in a group, so this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed up the routing and basically *excluded my own artifacts from the parent repository group*. When I browsed the child, the routing was fine. But browsing the parent group the routing prevented the artifacts to be found.

Removing the routing or adding the parent repository group to the route fixed this issue.